# Click on parent to open it's child inside collection(vanilla JS)

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to javascript, which is why I hope I could get an advise of how to make the following using vanilla JS.
I have structure

```
<div class="parent">
 <div class="child">Some content</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
 <div class="child">Some content</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
 <div class="child">Some content</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
 <div class="child">Some content</div>
</div>
```

What I want is to be able to click on each parent to open only it's own child. Could someone give an idea how that could be done with vanilla js? I assume this should be done using collections in JS. But I have no idea how to connect each parent and each child with each other. Would be grateful for any advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, need to get elements with class "`parent`"

with a for loop bind `addEventListener` of `onclick` function

in function find child div element with class "`child` "

then show the child element

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("parent");

var myFunction = function() {
    var childNode = this.querySelector('.child');
    childNode.style.display = "block";
};

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
}
```

```css
.child{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">p1
  <div class="child">p1 Some content</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">p2
  <div class="child">p2 Some content</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">p3
  <div class="child">p3 Some content</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">p4
  <div class="child">p4 Some content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It works like this (see comments in code):

```js
// Iterate over a collection of elements with class 'parent'
for (const parent of document.querySelectorAll('.parent')) {
  // to each parent, add a click listener
  parent.addEventListener('click', function(clickEvent) {
    // check if the element clicked was the parent and not a click bubbling up from a child
    if (clickEvent.target === parent) {
      // find the child contained
      const child = parent.querySelector('.child');
      // toggle the visibility using the hidden property
      child.hidden = !child.hidden;
    }
  })
}
```

```css
.parent::before { content: "parent, click here to toggle child"; }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
 <div class="child" hidden>Some content 1</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
 <div class="child" hidden>Some content 2</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
 <div class="child" hidden>Some content 3</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
 <div class="child" hidden>Some content 4</div>
</div>
```

Also note that HTML offers an element with this functionality already:

```html
<details>
  <div>Some content 1</div>
</details>
<details>
  <div>Some content 2</div>
</details>
<details>
  <div>Some content 3</div>
</details>
<details>
  <div>Some content 4</div>
</details>
```

Comment: thanks this is a good option. but I will require to animate children expanding (which I would try to accomplish by animating height property). So I am trying to start from understanding how it works in general.